# How can I limit a polar plot in radius while preserving the shape of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I'm currently trying to zoom in on a subset of the range of a polar plot in python, but when I do so, instead of preserving the arc length at the beginning portion of the subset, the plot compresses this portion of the plot down to a single point. I've included a generic example of the code below. I've also included the 3 plots that it creates for ease of viewing.

**Update:** After countless attempts, I still have not figured out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Plots are in the same order as shown in the plotting portion of the code]

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# initialize blank dataset to create blank polar plot.
r_max = 1 # max radius
r_spacing = 0.1 
t_max = 60 # max angle (in degrees)
t_spacing = 1

# radius dataset at 0.1 increments
r_dat = np.linspace(0,r_max,(r_max/r_spacing)+1)
# theta dataset at 1 degree increments
t_dat = np.linspace(0,t_max,(t_max/t_spacing)+1)*np.pi/180

# blank dataset to plot an empty polar plot
blank = np.empty([len(r_dat), len(t_dat)])
blank[:] = np.nan

# desired radius subset
r_lim0 = 0.4
r_lim1 = 1.0

# plot with full radius range
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, polar = True)
ax1.set_xlim(0,max(t_dat))
plt.contourf(t_dat, r_dat, blank)
plt.show()
plt.close()

# plot of the full radius range with the area of interest 
# shaded in blue (the blue shaded region shows the desired 
# region and desired shape of the subset plot I want)
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, polar = True)
ax2.set_xlim(0,max(t_dat))
plt.contourf(t_dat, r_dat, blank)
ax2.fill_between(t_dat,r_lim0,r_lim1)
plt.show()
plt.close()

# plot of the desired subset radius range
# the shape of the region is not maintained
fig3 = plt.figure()
ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(111, polar = True)
ax3.set_xlim(0,max(t_dat))
ax3.set_ylim(r_lim0,r_lim1)
plt.contourf(t_dat, r_dat, blank)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This example provides a solution: [mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axisartist-demo-floating-axes-py).

Here is the relevant bit, adapted to your needs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.projections import PolarAxes
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_finder import (FixedLocator, MaxNLocator,
                                                 DictFormatter)
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes  

def setup_axes(fig, rmin,rmax,amin,amax,rect=111):
    """
    With custom locator and formatter.
    Note that the extreme values are swapped.
    """
    tr = PolarAxes.PolarTransform()

    #pi = np.pi
    angle_ticks = [(amin, str(amin)),
                   (amax, str(amax))]

    grid_locator1 = FixedLocator([v for v, s in angle_ticks])
    tick_formatter1 = DictFormatter(dict(angle_ticks))

    grid_locator2 = MaxNLocator(2)

    grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(
        tr, extremes=(amax, amin, rmax, rmin),
        grid_locator1=grid_locator1,
        grid_locator2=grid_locator2,
        tick_formatter1=tick_formatter1,
        tick_formatter2=None)

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(
        rect, axes_class=floating_axes.FloatingAxes, grid_helper=grid_helper)
    ax1.grid()

    # create a parasite axes whose transData in RA, cz
    aux_ax = ax1.get_aux_axes(tr)

    aux_ax.patch = ax1.patch  # for aux_ax to have a clip path as in ax
    ax1.patch.zorder = 0.9  # but this has a side effect that the patch is
    # drawn twice, and possibly over some other
    # artists. So, we decrease the zorder a bit to
    # prevent this.

    return ax1, aux_ax

fig=plt.figure()
rmin=np.amin(radii)
rmax=np.amax(radii)
amin=np.amin(angles)
amax=np.amax(angles)
ax, aux_ax = setup_axes(fig,rmin,rmax,amin,amax)
aux_ax.pcolor(angles,radii,data)
plt.show()
```

I'm still working it out, but this should be a good start. Also, I'm not sure how to rotate the tick labels if it were necessary.